# Как сделать триггером изменение пользователем цвета фона ячейки

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть задача - рассчитывать значение разными формулами в зависимости от цвета ячейки в Google Sheets. Расчеты делаю скриптом.
К сожалению человек так устроен, что сначала он вводит значение и потом меняет цвет ячейки. И по этому мне ни чего не остается, как положить еще одну общую ячейку, в которой человек кликает для смены флага Истина/Ложь и тут по onEdit я пересчитываю формулу.

ВОПРОС: Можно ли как то сделать так, чтоб изменение пользователем цвета фона ячейки являлось триггером для пересчета скрипта? Это нужно чтоб исключить возможные ошибки в расчетах из-за забывчивости пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en&authuser=19) и [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable?hl=en&authuser=19) - такого события не существует.

Может поможет триггер [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en&authuser=19#onselectionchangee), который реагирует на изменение выделения:

> The onSelectionChange(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet.

Так же, если юзеру не важно видеть изменения тут и сейчас можете использовать [onOpen(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?authuser=19#onopene) и пересчитывать формулы при открытии

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это работает при выборе ячейки. Но изменения цвета ячейки это не чувствует.

Comment: Ясное дело. Именно это я и написал в первом предложении - такого события не существует. Но может Вам подойдет логика других триггеров? Можете еще посмотреть на временные триггеры (раз в n секунд запуск и проверять цвета в ячейках, сравнивая с запомненными)